# $urlProvider not resolvable in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can inject `$urlProvider` in `module.config()` but when i try to do it in `module.controller()` I am getting this error:

```
Unknown provider: $urlRouterProviderProvider <- $urlRouterProvider <- MyCtrl
```

I have included `angular-ui`, also imported `ui.router` in the module.

I cannot see anybody doing this online, but why should it not work?

Answer (score 2):

Providers are meant to be configured in the config phase, and then they can be injected into a `controller`, or the `run` phase, sans the `Provider` post-fix:

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
});

app.run('MyCtrl', function($urlRouter) { // no Provider post-fix
   $urlRouter.listen();
});
```

See [the Angular docs on Providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) and the [UI-Router's guide on `$urlRouterProvider`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider) for more information.